# Python function is not behaving as expected

Tags: python

I have a package called `'Learning'`, conatins an empty file `__init__.py` and `hello_calvin.py`

hello_calvin.py contents:

```
def hi_calvin(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c
```

hello_john.py contents:

```
from Learning import hello_calvin

a = hello_calvin.hi_calvin(1,2)
print(a)
```

However, print(a) doesn't print anything.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help appreciated!!

Edit: Sorry I renamed the correct files. It makes sense now

Comment: where is hello_calvin defined? hi_calvin is defined in hello_john.py?

Comment: `a = hello_john.hi_calvin(1,2)`

Comment: @garg10may: Yes! along with `from Learning import hello_john`

Comment: Would you need to change it to: print a rather than print(a)

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4, if I drop off the brackets it will not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, I just did shift + ctrl f10 on PyCharm and that ran the **init**.py which is empty so it printed nothing.

Sorry guys!

Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rename your file `init.py` to `__init__.py` this is the correct way to tells Python to treat this directory as a package.

Then, it should work ok. I tried in my computer and it works fine.

Comment: @Carols, He type `__init__.py` only, It's Stack overflow behavior to format a string with '__' as a prefix and suffix will be converted to bold.

Comment: I see. That's why the `init` he wrote is bold. Thanks for the note ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should have been getting the error,

```
ImportError: No module named Learning
```

because your __init__.py is empty. Change a few things.

1. Make hello_calvin.py a class.
   so

   ```
   Class Hello_calvin:
       def hi_calvin(a, b):
           c = a + b
           return c
   ```

   and save the file with the class name 'Hello_calvin.py'
2. __init__.py shouldn't be empty.
   Type

   ```
   from Learning import Hello_Calvin
   ```

This tells python that it is package directory.

The name of the package directory should be 'Learning'.

Also, 'hello_john.py' should not be in the directory Learning, since it is accessing the package.

Look through this http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/ .